# How to stop NavMeshAgent resetting rotation

Tags: unity, navmesh

I'm prototyping a 2.5D style game. I have my sprites angled at a 33° angle on the x axis.

I'm using the NavMeshAgent for basic navigation and pathfinding. I've set the Angular Speed to 0, to prevent the auto rotation to the destination.

But the x rotation is always reset to 0 on play. Is there a setting I'm missing, or do I need to set the rotation in script?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set `navmeshAgent.updateRotation = false` in a script. See [updateRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-updateRotation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Adding this Code worked for me.

```
private void Start()
{
    // Store the initial rotation
    initialRotation = transform.rotation;
    
    // Get the NavMeshAgent component
    navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (navMeshAgent.velocity != Vector3.zero)
    {
        // Apply the initial rotation
        transform.rotation = initialRotation;
    }
}
```